# Separate columns in .txt file in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The raw .txt file looks like this

```
e1 47 3 Self-emp-inc Married-civ-spouse Transport-moving White Male Cuba                                                                                                                                                                                  
e2 52 16 Self-emp-not-inc Married-civ-spouse Prof-specialty White Male United-States                                                                                                                                                                      
e3 26 9 Private Divorced Craft-repair White Male United-States                                                                                                                                                                                            
e4 60 9 Private Married-civ-spouse Craft-repair White Male United-States
```

I have tried

```
adult = pd.read_csv("Adult/dataset_full.txt", header=None)
```

It only gives get ONE column. If used `sep=' '` it gives

```
<Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 187 fields in line 3, saw 197>
```

Have tried `skiprows=,` `read_fwf()`, `read_table()` gives all similar result.

Does anyone have any insights on how to separate this file into columns?

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be able to do it directly because you have spaces as a separator and values like "White Male" which have space inside them. You'll have to read the data line by line and split the rows into a list of values manually

Comment: It also looks like you txt file has many spaces after each line, which may interfere with pandas reading tools when you use `sep=' '`. Try with `sep='\s+'`

Answer (score 0):

If your `file.txt` is this:

```
e1 47 3 Self-emp-inc Married-civ-spouse Transport-moving White Male Cuba
e2 52 16 Self-emp-not-inc Married-civ-spouse Prof-specialty White Male United-States
e3 26 9 Private Divorced Craft-repair White Male United-States
e4 60 9 Private Married-civ-spouse Craft-repair White Male United-States
```

Then you have four rows with `9` values separated by a space. So you can:

- read the file line by line
- strip and split the line on space
- pass this to a `pandas` `DataFrame`
- (optional) create `headers` for columns
- finally dump this to a `.csv` file

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

with open("file.txt") as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame([line.strip().split() for line in f.readlines()])
    headers = [f"Col{i}" for i in range(1, 10)]
    df.to_csv("your_table.csv", index=False, header=headers)
```

Output:

[image]